# php-fpm forever respawning children when executing uglifycss

Tags: php, centos, uglifycss

I have such line in a php application:

```
exec('uglifycss 1.css 2.css > main.css');
```

After executing it, php-fpm starts to restart all children non stopping, which leads to 100% cpu on a server in seconds. Only service php-fpm restart saves the situation. All other parts of app work well and exec with other commands (uglifyjs, ssconvert, wkhtmltopdf) work well, only this line causes such troubles.

Executing `uglifycss` in bash works well, disabling opcache does not help, all the permissions are correct, changing uglifycss version does not help. The line itself works well - minified file appears in a folder.

Php-fpm logs:

```
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:39] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 21162
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:39] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:39] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21199 exited with code 0 after 0.011741 seconds from start
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21200 started
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21200 exited with code 0 after 0.012848 seconds from start
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21201 started
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21201 exited with code 0 after 0.011070 seconds from start
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21202 started
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21202 exited with code 0 after 0.012875 seconds from start
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21203 started
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21203 exited with code 0 after 0.012139 seconds from start
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21204 started
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21204 exited with code 0 after 0.012334 seconds from start
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21205 started
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21205 exited with code 0 after 0.011729 seconds from start
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21206 started
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21206 exited with code 0 after 0.010936 seconds from start
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21207 started
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21207 exited with code 0 after 0.011194 seconds from start
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21208 started
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21208 exited with code 0 after 0.011382 seconds from start
[07-Jun-2017 00:10:59] NOTICE: [pool app] child 21209 started
```

and so on until service won't be manually restarted...

Server info:

```
CentOS 7, php 7.1.5, node 8.0.0, npm 5.0.0, uglifycss 0.0.27
```

Seems like a bug, does anyone have the same issue? Is there any fix to this?

Comment: This is possibly the same as https://serverfault.com/questions/837200/why-is-php-fpm-spawning-and-destroying-hundreds-of-children-per-second-with-no-s/837211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a php-fpm bug related to use of exec/passthru in child processes. It's due to contention for stdin. The fix can be seen in this PR: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/3287 which has been merged into php 7.1.